# Can I move armor stand legs up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an armor stand look like its flying with elytra, and I can't seem to get it right. The command I'm using is:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoBasePlate:1b,ShowArms:1b,Rotation:[53f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{},{}],Pose:{Body:[38f,0f,0f],LeftLeg:[66f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[64f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[257f,0f,0f],RightArm:[253f,0f,0f]}}
```

But the legs are too far down and all I can do is rotate them :/ is there something I can add or another command that I can use? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the datapack for custom armor stands at VanillaTweaks.net, it can be used to move the stands using a book.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't possible in vanilla means with commands?

Comment: it is possible, this is much simpler and more reliable.